# possible to get current desktop to show on MacOS lockcreen?

Tags: macos, applescript, screen-capture, screen-lock

I'm using MacOS Ventura on my MBP laptop (no external displays). For reasons I don't want to get into, I would like my lockscreen to display whatever was showing on my desktop around the time it (i.e the lockscreen) kicked in. Ideally I would've liked to have a "transparent" lockscreen, so that an onlooker could basically view my desktop but is unable to interact with it without logging in.. but I'm guessing that sort of thing is going to be fundamentally disallowed by the OS for security reasons.

I'd settle for a solution that (for instance) periodically takes screenshots of my desktop and will swap over to the screenshot when the lockscreen activates - whether due to timeout or when manually triggered with the `Ctrl+Cmd+Q` shortcut - and then reverts to the regular background image when I log back in.

Assuming no one has a cut-and-dried solution that just works, would something like this be possible with say, AppleScript or another scripting tool like [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/)? I've not used either of these tools before, but would be open to seeking out a scripting solution on my own if it's viable. Or am I going to run into insurmountable security restrictions?